# Given a field $L$ with $q$ elements and I have $[K:L] = n$, does $K$ then have $q^n$ elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I think of it like this:

We let $K$ be a vector field over $F$. Then, every $\alpha\in K$ be represented uniquely as
$$
\alpha = l_1k_1 + \ldots l_nk_n
$$
where $k_1,\ldots, k_n$ is a fixed basis of $K$, and $l_1,\ldots, l_n\in L$.

Thus, for each $k_i$, we have a choice of $q$ scalars. Thus, we have $q^n$ different linear combinations. Since each vector has a unique representation, and every linear combination must be contained in our vector space, $K$ has $q^n$ elements.

Is there anything wrong with this proof?

Comment: Yes, $K$ as a vector space over $L$ is isomorphic to $L^n,$ so it has $q^n$ elements.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct.